Possibly isekai, village-building manga in which a mermaid moves in with and says she will be the wife of the main character
I forgot if the main character (MC) is banished, but he created a village with a castle that has a lake in the back. Later on, a princess mermaid moves in and says that she will be the wife of the MC. The mermaid and the villager/citizens started doing trades. I'm not sure if it's correct, but there was a scene where the MC routed the water river to the castle's moat for protection.
The MC is still a kid. The mermaid is also still a kid with his father and the rest their mermaid citizen who moves in at the lake. The story is similar to farming in another world.

Is this Let's Buy the Land and Cultivate It in a Different World...?

Itonami Noria was summoned into another world. However, he did not possess any “skills” which any inhabitant of the other world all held. Evaluated as useless, he was casted out to the uninhabited land. Although appearing to lack any skills at first glance, Norio actually had the special gift “Ultimate Supporter”. Seeking a sense of adventure in another world, Itonami Noria christened himself as Kidan, and decides to cultivate the land. With his ability, “Ultimate Supporter”, he is able to make use to anything in his hand to maximum efficiency, gradually cultivating the land for use. One day, while fishing at the seaside, he caught a beautiful mermaid! She names herself as Pratty, and announces that she shall become his wife for catching her—!?

A Japanese 'corporate drone' is summoned to a kingdom in another world, but is assessed as having no skill. Since they can't send him back and don't know what else to do with him, the King agrees to his request to be given a plot of land where he can live out the rest of his days.
When he arrives at the plot of land, he decides to build his own kingdom there and starts ploughing the land to grow crops. He also goes fishing in a lake he finds there and catches a mermaid, who insists he must take responsibility for having done so and marry her.




Thanks for the suggestion but what I am looking for is a different one. The MC is still a kid. The mermaid is also still a kid with his father and the rest their mermaid citizen who moves in at the lake. The story is similar to farming in another world.

Btw, loved this series. specially his lich teacher.

Name: Fun Territory Defense by the Optimistic Lord.
Guy's father kicks him out. He saves a village. Builds a wall. Builds a lake. Gets merfolk to live in the lake and they try to marry their young daughter to him, etc.



I was looking for the same one myself, and just found it.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Instead of just posting a link to a video, which will probably disappear in a few days or weeks, please name the work and describe it, explaining how it matches the question.

Name: Fun Territory Defense by the Optimistic Lord
Guys father kicks him out. He saves a village. Builds a wall. Builds a lake. Gets merfolk to live in the lake and they try to marry their young daughter to him, etc.
I had stumbled across this in my search to re-watch the thing, and figured I would at least post an answer. Sorry if it aint up to your standards.

@Anon: The point is to actually post that in your answer.  It's an easy [edit].
